# How can I create a new Request in Laravel 5 Middleware

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have urls that are prefixed with the locale, I want to save the local and modify the request without redirecting it, how can I modify the request before passing it on?

So for a url like site.com/en/someurl

```
class GetLocale implements Middleware {
 public function handle($request, Closure $next)
 {
    $segment = Request::segment(1); // 'en'
    if( is_valid_language($segment) ){
         // remove local from the request url
         // do something to remove the local and continue
         // as if the url was site.com/someurl
         return $next($request);
    }

    return $next($request);
 }

}
```

After GetLocale runs, the rest of the site should totally ignore the locale and see only site.com/someurl.

(This is so we can use locales and route annotations at the same time and still keep the original headers, post data etc.)**

Answer (score 3):

The Laravel Request class has a `duplicate()` method that allows you to create a duplicate request and override certain parts of it

The underlying Symfony request checks server vars and headers to determine the request URL on the `prepareRequestUri()`.

It seems that overriding the `REQUEST_URI` server variable on the request (`$server` on the `duplicate()` method) should help you rewrite the URL without the locale fragment. However, this seems like a very hack-ish solution

---

Reference: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Http/Request.php#L613